# Emergence of English as the dominant mathematical language

Tags: ho.history-overview, reference-request

My impression is that most math papers (and almost all of the most important ones) are now published in English.  Not long ago (historically) publishing in French, German, Russian, etc. were more common.  I'm curious when and how this transition occurred, and what it looked like while it was happening.

Of course English is the dominant language for many other areas such as publications in the sciences in general, international business, the internet, etc.  Nonetheless I have the impression that the transition occurred later and more slowly in math than in some of these other areas.  This may be false; I don't know why I think this.

Perhaps I have this idea because math graduate programs are unique among technical fields in having a language requirement, though that could also be explained by our tendency to read more old papers than say, biologists.  But it seems plausible that the transition would occur later in math because math can be more easily undertaken as a solitary activity than the sciences.

My main question is: where would I find data on the representation of different languages in papers in top math journals as, say, a fraction of total papers?  Of course I could try to determine what the top journals were at various times and go through their tables of contents for each issue and compile such data myself.  But it seems plausible someone may have already done a study of this and in much more depth than I would have time to do by myself.

Secondarily, perhaps there are published anecdotal accounts about how and when this transition occurred?  I can imagine there may have been resistance by some.  It may have happened at different times in different subfields for different reasons.  Perhaps some landmark papers in English paved the way.

I would be grateful for pointers to literature examining any of these issues.  Comparisons with other fields such as physics would also be interesting, but I'm primarily interested in math.

Comment: The transition was called the Second World War.


Comment: As a start, look at the (recently online) lists of invited talks at the ICM's.  You might also see what historical information is kept by the IMU.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.08.26 .

Comment: @Jose: Interesting.  I can see why that might have happened in the case of physics.  Do you know why it also happened then for math?

Comment: @Gerhard: On the <a href="http://www.mathunion.org/o/ICM/Speakers/SortedByCongress.php">IMU website</a> I see the list of plenary and invited speakers along with their subfields, but no title or other information to indicate language.  Was there another page you had in mind?

Comment: Publishing in French still occurs. For example, Toen writes much in french: http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Toen_B/0/1/0/all/0/1 . Most work of Serre is published in French - but this may not really count since he is born before the war. The last famous article in German I am aware of is Faltings' famous Endlichkeitssätze für abelsche Varietäten über Zahlkörpern. 

Comment: I wonder if the people who still write in their native (non-English) language realize that they are damaging other non-natives English speakers much more than native anglophones.

Comment: It's probably hard to assign any specific date to the transition, which started a long time ago but was certainly hastened by the effects of World War II in Europe and elsewhere including a massive migration of mathematicians from their home countries.   Journals show interesting transitions: for instance, Math. Sbornik at one time published papers in languages other than Russian.   Only recently *Mathematical Reviews* abandoned their older practice of publishing reviews in languages like French and German.   (But if attending Paris conferences you should know some French.)

Comment: A side comment is that math Ph.D. programs in the US are less and less insistent that their students pass foreign language exams, partly because so many of those students are already at least bilingual.  My department at UMass is an example.   

Comment: Noah, many prominent mathematicians emigrated from Germany to the US (and many others perished under the Nazis), I think that it was even more pronounced than in the case of physicists. The prominence of German mathematical journals started to decline in the mid 1930s. Here is a secondary indicator: Zentralblatt was supplemented, and eventually, overtaken in importance, by the Math Reviews.

Comment: Although a lot of major journals will still accept articles written in languages other than English, I wonder what role the requirements of some journals has played in this shift.

Comment: I remember Gerhard Huisken saying he was not sure it was even a good idea that all papers move to English, and regretting that he did not always know the German words for concepts (in mean curvature flow) because he learned them in Australia in English. One can understand his sadness on this. $$ $$ In integral quadratic forms, one of the big names is Rainer Schulze-Pillot, who wrote his important early work in German, switching to English around 1986. I can just imagine the inner dialogue, "What's so bad about my language? Plenty of people speak my language, many more read it. However,..." 

Comment: To see "what it looked like while it was happening", as a case study you can browse the first few volumes of Inventiones, which was founded in 1966. There was a mix of papers written in German, French, and English (I think that papers in Russian were allowed but I cannot recall seeing any). Amazingly, the current instructions at the Springer website make no mention of the languages in which the manuscripts are accepted.

Comment: One of the last multilingual journal was the *Archives of Rational Mechanics and Analysis*, till around less than 20 years ago. Its preface stated, if I remember well: "The languages of the A.R.M.A. are English, French, German, Italian, and Latin".

Comment: The A.R.M.A. published Clifford Truesdell's paper:
Solutio generalis et accurata problematum quamplurimorum
de motu corporum elasticorum incomprimibilium in
deformationibus valde magnis,
Vol. 11 (1962) pp. 106--113.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because I don't know myself, but I'd have to believe that Springer must have some repository of data on this. If not, it must be relatively easy to glean from their records given their catalogue of high quality journals like Annalen and Inventiones which have at least over time been multilingual.

Comment: @Robin: wasn't ARMA founded by Cliff Truesdell? I vaguely remember something about the fact that ARMA's five languages are the five languages Truesdell was fluent in.

Comment: Also, Charlie Fefferman's first paper (when he was 15, so that makes it roughly 1963-64) was in German. Take from it what you will. 

Comment: @RC: There's also: Schechtman, Vadim. Definitio nova algebroidis verticiani. (Latin. English summary) Studies in Lie theory, 443--494, Progr. Math., 243, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 2006. (But that's not in a journal.)

Comment: The American mathematicians John Brillhart and Pat Morton published a paper in German in the Illinois Journal in 1978. Math Reviews noted that "The summary is written in flawless English." 

Comment: To Noah:  At mathunion.org/ICM, the volumes containing plenary and invited addresses (no short communication abstracts, unfortunately) are searchable.  The 1893 edition has titles in English, French and German, possibly other languages.  Gerhard "One more day in Hyderabad" Paseman, 2010.08.27 IST

Comment: I can't resist quoting the following from "On Hilbert's Thirteenth Problem and Related Questions," by A.G. Vitushnik, Russian Math Surveys, 2004.

Comment: "When [Shannon] visited Moscow State University, he asked...to arrange a meeting with Kolmogorov...The meeting was very short. Apparently, this was due to the language barrier as well. Kolmogorov was fluent in French and German and read English well, but his spoken English was not very good. Shannon, with some sympathy, expressed his regret that they could not understand each other well. Kolmogorov replied that there were five international languages, he could speak three of them, and, if his interlocutor were also able to speak three languages, then they would have no problems." 

Comment: @alex, this should go into the thread about applications of the pigeonhole principle. 

Comment: Note that Ngo published the proof of the Fundamental Lemma in French, in *Publications mathématiques de l'IHES* which regularly publishes  in French. You also see papers in French from time to time in Annals of Mathematics (the last volume contains one by Le Roux).

Comment: Ngo, Frenkel, and Langlands had a paper after that, also in French. Given that Langlands is native and Frenkel is near-native in English, this seemed rather odd. http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4578

Comment: It's true that papers are still sometimes published in French, German and Russian.  But how recently were people regularly publishing in these languages who had no obvious connection to the relevant Sprachraum?

Comment: Some data: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7720

Answer (score 17):

Now that [the texts of all of the Plenary talks](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/) at the international congresses of mathematicians is available online, that could serve as a data source for the transition. This year, every plenary talk was in English, and none of the speakers (that I attended) were at all difficult to understand, at least not on account of the language.

Here are some years, and the number of Invited plenary Speakers whose title is in (English, French, German, Russian).

- 1920: ( 2, 3, 0, 0), in Strasbourg
- 1932: ( 2, 9, 9, 1), in Zurich
- 1936: ( 7, 2,12, 0), in Oslo
- 1950: (19, 2, 1, 0), in Cambridge
- 1954: (14, 3, 2, 1), in Amsterdam
- 1958: (13, 3, 2, 1), in Edinburgh
- 1962: ( 9, 3, 1, 3), in Stockholm
- 1966: ( 9, 1, 2, 5), in Moscow
- 1970: (15, 1, 0, 0), in Nice
- 1974: (15, 2, 0, 0), in Vancouver
- 1978: (17, 0, 0, 0), in Helsinki
- 1983: (12, 0, 0, 0), in Warsaw
- 1986: (13, 0, 1, 1), in Berkeley
- 1994: (14, 0, 0, 0), in Zurich
- 1998: (15, 0, 0, 0), in Kyoto
- 2002: (19, 1, 0, 0), in Beijing
- 2006: (19, 0, 0, 0), in Madrid

  So the supposition that World War II is the cause isn't supported by this data. Certainly it impacted the use of German, but other languages were common until the 1970s. Something drastic seems to have happened between 1966 and 1970.

Comment: Kevin, there is a huge change for German (your 3rd coordinate) from 1936 to 1950. The war happened in between and is the natural explanation if one takes into account the movement of many top German mathematicians to other countries in the 30s and 40s. Although WWII did not completely eliminate mathematical research articles written in German, it was very much reduced as an effect of the war and the downward trajectory was set. 
 

Comment: And taking in geopolitics, it is not hard to see why there were a resurgent of Russian talks in 1962 ad 1966. With only 3 data points pre-war, your data cannot really be used to support *anything*, especially since the 1950 and 58 meetings were held in English speaking cities. 

Comment: @Willie: I think the reason for Russian talks in 1966 is obvious.


Answer (score 12):

This makes a little bit more precise what has already been said in the comments. 
This [list](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_bekannter_deutschsprachiger_Emigranten_und_Exilanten_%281933%E2%80%931945%29) of emigrants (most of them were forced to leave since they 
lost their jobs; this applies to Emmy Noether, Richard Brauer, and later to Artin,
who had a Jewish wife. Siegel, as far as I know, left because he couldn't stand the situation).

One reason for founding the Mathematical Reviews, by the way, was the pressure on the Zentralblatt put up by German mathematicians (including Hasse) not to let emigrants 
review articles by Germans.

French and Russian were widely used after World War II because these countries had
excellent and very influential mathematicians at the time.

Comment: So it seems this is a big part of the answer for the decreasing use of German, but does not necessarily address French or Russian.  Perhaps someone else could comment on how publishing in those languages began to decrease?

Comment: Russian saw a big decline after the end of the Soviet Union, when many Russian mathematicians moved to the West and they had an incentive to publish in English to reach a broader audience. The French are still fighting their losing battle :-)

Comment: Even before the collapse of the USSR, in what major international journals based outside the Soviet Union were articles regularly published in Russian? I don't think I've ever seen any in Crelle or the Annals. (They did appear in Acta Arithmetica, probably since its home base was in Poland, although nothing of the sort has appeared there since the late 90s acc. to MathSciNet.)



Comment: There's a stereotype of the French as being very proud of their language; this may have something to do with why they fight that battle.

Comment: @Michael Lugo: I tend to think that a very deep an important paper deserves to be published in the author's mother tongue unless she or he is *really* fluent in english. Such a paper is susceptible to carry subtle discussions, that need a precise use of the language. It will be read by lots of people, and that increases the need to be well-written. Besides, if it is important enough, it will easily find a translator.

Comment: @Keith Publ Math IHES.

Comment: Felipe: I found three such papers in Publ. Math. IHES on MathSciNet, all in the 60s. That's not quite as "regular" as I had in mind, but maybe I did not do my search correctly. 

Comment: @Benoit, I agree that using one's mother tongue is necessary for the most precise use of language.  The **mathematical** part of the article, the equations and the symbols and the axioms and the proofs are necessary but **not sufficient**.  The glue of the mathematical journal article is in the words linking the path marked out by the mathematical terminology.  Mathematics may appear to be the one topic or subject matter ou the <<langage qu'on parle>> should not matter, but this is not true.  I agree with you that one should write in one's mother tongue, for precisely your reasons.

Comment: @Keith It's true that Russians primarily published papers in Russian in their own journals.

Comment: @sleepless in beantown: I want to stress that even the proofs are written in some language, which shall be well mastered at some place even though most of them only need basic language.  

Comment: @Benoit: I don't buy your argument at all. Great mathematicians are not necessarily good writers (or speakers, for that matter). Does that mean that we should also get them a writer to polish their paper, before sending it to the translator? The French math literature is filled with really well-written paper, but I see that more as the by-product of the type of education received, that stressed good writing in French and not so much in English. From what I can tell, the upcoming generations have a much easier time with English, and writing in that language will not be a problem.

Comment: @Thierry, if ones accepts the contention that "great mathematicians are not necessarily good writers...or speakers", then would it not make more sense to allow themselves to express themselves with the language in which they are most comfortable?  The language (or for many people one of the multiple) language(s) that they learned as a child can be used without stumbling over the basics of word order, or (as Benoît mentioned) allow the use of nuanced words and phrases more correctly. The meaning may not come through. I was agreeing completely with Benoît, but his reply shows I was not clear.

Answer (score 4):

Long comment:

MathSciNet can help you try to compile some rough statistics yourself with a *bit* less work than reading all the titles in a given journal.  Their data include the language (if not English) of each indexed article.  I don't think it appears in any of the individually searchable fields, but it is found in an "Anywhere" search.  (Unfortunately, this will also catch articles with a "summary" in a non-English language.)  So, for example, by searching with "Annals of Mathematics" in the Journal field and "French" in the Anywhere field, I found seven papers written in French published in the *Annals of Mathematics* in the last five years, the most recent being "Le lemme fondamental pour les groupes unitaires" by Gérard Laumon and Bao Châu Ngô.

Comment: Also: the last German paper in the Annals was in 1989.

Comment: In Inventiones the last German paper was published in 1993, and in JAMS (which only started in 1988) there's a unique one and that in 1990. None in Pub. IHES, not surprisingly. In Acta Math. I can't tell because mathscinet has some erroneous information, but I think none after 1982.

Comment: I think he likes his names in traditional Vietnamese order (excuse the lack of accents): Ngo Bao Chau .  Or is this another author?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.08.27 IST

Comment: This is the same author, and yes, he writes his name as Ngo Bao Chau.

Comment: For the purposes of accurate quotation, I copied Ngo's name directly from the paper in *Annals*.  I also have heard he writes his name in traditional Vietnamese order, but at least in this case, *Annals* wrote it as "Bao Châu Ngô".  A quick perusal of his other published papers suggests this is the order he always uses in publication.

Comment: ... or rather more likely, the order forced upon him by the copy editors of certain journals. 

Comment: Yes, good point.

Answer (score 4):

In Physics and in Chemistry, particularly in Organic Chemistry, German was the *lingua franca*, the bridging language which it was necessary to know how to read and how to publish in, as the leading journals and the leading scientists communicated in German, but that was in the 19th century and the early parts of the 20th century.  The mass exodus of scientists from Germany starting immediately prior to the Second World War seems to be a big part of the change, at least in the Physical Sciences.

Comment: I just realized José Figueroa-O'Farrill mentioned the second World War in the comments to the question.  I should add also that along with the exodus, there was also the "draw in", as the United States Governmental entities and Universities also pulled in German scientists and foreign graduate students.  The perception that the hottest physical science research was being performed in the USA led to many graduate students choosing to come to the USA and to scientists agreeing to emigrate to the USA.